# Trouble with UI for avatar creator. Populating list requires double click instead of 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem Description**

I am fairly new to html, css and javascript, more so javascript than the former two and I'm looking for advice on some code for my personal project. You can see an example in the code snippet below (there are no images).

I am trying to create the UI for a "character creator" or "avatar creator". Something like: https://avatarmaker.com/

I have basically achieved this but i've run into a few problems. The way the program populates the orange area is by changing the css display from "none" to "display". The problem with this is it requires a double click to change populated area. Also the code is very messy.

I have attempted to streamline the code with a for loop in the "Attempt at Changing Javascreipt". But it doesn't work at all.

So if anyone has any advice to streamline any of this code it would be very much appreciated.

```js
/*
const toggleChoices = document.querySelectorAll("#headchoices, #torsochoices, #legschoices, #backchoices, #handchoices, #waistchoices, #feetchoices, #mainhandchoices, #offhandchoices");

function getHead() {
let arraylength = toggleChoices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
    if toggleChoices[i].style.display === "block" {
      toggleChoices[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  let toggleHead = document.getElementById("headchoices");
    if (toggleHead.style.display === "none") {
      toggleHead.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
*/

//let toggleDisplayStatus === FALSE;

function getHead() {
  let toggleHead = document.getElementById("headchoices");
  if (toggleHead.style.display === "none") {
    toggleHead.style.display = "block";
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("torsochoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("legschoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("backchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("handchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("waistchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("feetchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("mainhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("offhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
}

function getTorso() {
  let toggleTorso = document.getElementById("torsochoices");
  if (toggleTorso.style.display === "none") {
    toggleTorso.style.display = "block";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("headchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("legschoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("backchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("handchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("waistchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("feetchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("mainhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("offhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
}

function getLegs() {
  let toggleLegs = document.getElementById("legschoices");
  if (toggleLegs.style.display === "none") {
    toggleLegs.style.display = "block";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("headchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("torsochoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("backchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("handchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("waistchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("feetchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("mainhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("offhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
STYLE SHEET */ @font-face {
  src: url(../../fonts/KGTangledUpInYou.ttf);
  font-family: tang1;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(../../fonts/KGTangledUpInYou2.ttf);
  font-family: tang2;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

hmtl {
  height: 100%;
}


/* ///////////////////////////////// SCROLLBAR STYLING //////////////////////////////// */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #a76e59;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #fad4b3;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #2d2524;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------NAVIGATION BAR--------------------------------------------------------------------
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------NAVIGATION BAR--------------------------------------------------------------------

/* BANNER COLOR AND SIZE */

.navbar {
  min-height: 5vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2d2524;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo_short {
  padding: 0.5% 3%;
}


/* spacing and alignment of nav links   */

.nav-links {
  padding: 0.5% 2%;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}


/* getting rid of bullit points (making horizontal row) and adding padding within the header boarder */

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  /* distance between eachother  */
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: #fad4b3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5625rem;
  /*25px; /* 36 pt  */
  font-family: tang2;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: -2px 3px 2px #1f1d1c;
  /* text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit; */
}


/*HOVER EFFECT */

.nav-links ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}


/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// SIDEBAR///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #a65c41;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left 0.4s ease;
  z-index: 10;
}

.btn.click {
  left: 260px;
}

.btn span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.btn.click span:before {
  content: '\f00d';
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -250px;
  background: #a65c41;
  transition: left 0.4s ease;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sidebar.show {
  left: 0px;
}

.sidebar .text {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fad4b3;
  text-shadow: -2px 3px 2px #1f1d1c;
  font-family: tang2;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #a65c41;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .text:hover {
  color: #F8F5FA;
}

.sidebar ul {
  background: #a65c41;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  line-height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #F8F5FA;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: tang2;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-weight: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar ul li a:hover {
  background: #a76e59;
}


/* SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS   */


/* SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS   */

.iconsS {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 350px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.iconsS ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* LINE GONE */
}

.iconsS ul a {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fad4b3;
  height: 50px;
  /* background box height */
  width: 50px;
  /* background box width */
  background: #a76e59;
  margin: 5px;
  /* sitance between eachother */
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .iconsS a:hover {
  background: #2d2524;
}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////*/

@media(max-width: 950px) {
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo_short {
    padding: 1% 4%;
    display: flex;
  }
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------Panel 1------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------Panel 1------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.etypeselector {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80vh;
  background: #a65c41;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.etypeselector ul {
  display: block;
}

.etypeselector ul button {
  display: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #a65c41;
}

.etypeselector ul button img {
  display: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding-top: .6em;
  padding-bottom: .6em;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// CHOISES MENU /////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

.echoices {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background: #a65c41;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.colourbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  background: #a76e59;
  /* #a65c41; */
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 12px 12px 12px;
}

.colourbar h1 {
  color: #fad4b3;
  /* color of links (white)  */
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /*25px; /* 36 pt  */
  font-family: tang2;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: -2px 3px 2px #1f1d1c;
  /* text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit; */
}

.echoices button {
  display: relative;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  background: #a76e59;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.echoices button img {
  display: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

#headchoices {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 70%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#torsochoices,
#legschoices {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 70%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleE.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- edge of website should follow edge of device -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/976d327f90.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <title>Equipment Selector</title>

</head>

<body>
  <!--   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  NAVIGATION BAR //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
  <section class="navbar">
    <!-- NAVIGATION Links -->
    <nav>

      <div class="logo_short">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="../../images/DoMH_short.png" width="135px" height="35px"></a>
        <!-- LOGO LINK -->
      </div>

      <!-- NAVIGATION TOP BAR LINKS -->

      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i><a/></li>  <!-- BACK A PAGE -->
            <li><a href="pages/login/login.html"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i><a/></li> <!-- LOGOUT -->
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </section>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////SIDEBAR///////////////////////////////-->
  <div class="btn">
     <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
  </div>
  <section class="sidebar">
     <div class="text">
        SUBSCRIBE
     </div>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Suggestions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Changelog</a></li>

          <div class="iconsS">
            <ul>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-discord fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/deckofmanyheros" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </ul>

  </section>

  <!--   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  EQUIPMENT SELECTOR //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="characterwrapper">

    </div>

    <section class="etypeselector">
      <!-- Equiptment TYPE Selector i.e. "Head Piece", "body" etc. -->
      <ul>
        <button onclick="getHead()" type="button" name="head"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getTorso()" type="button" name="torso"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getLegs()" type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getBack()" type="button" name="back"><img src="equipment-icons\Cloak.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getHands()" type="button" name="hands"><img src="equipment-icons\Gloves.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getWaist()" type="button" name="waist"><img src="equipment-icons\Waist.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getFeet()" type="button" name="feet"><img src="equipment-icons\Boots.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getMainhand()" type="button" name="mainhand"><img src="equipment-icons\MainHand.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getOffhand()" type="button" name="offhand"><img src="equipment-icons\Offhand.png" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getAccesories()" type="button" name="accesories"><img src="" alt=""></button>
        <button onclick="getAura()" type="button" name="aura"><img src="" alt=""></button>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="echoices">
      <!-- Equiptment Selector - type assets-->
      <div class="colourbar">
        <h1>COLOUR BAR GOES HERE</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="headchoices">
        <button type="button" name="head1"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head2"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head3"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head4"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head5"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head6"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head7"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head8"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head9"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head10"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head11"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head12"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head13"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head14"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head15"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head16"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head17"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head18"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
      </div>
      <div id="torsochoices">
        <button type="button" name="head"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="torso"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="back"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="hands"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="waist"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="feet"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="mainhand"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="offhand"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="head"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="torso"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="back"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="hands"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="waist"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="feet"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="mainhand"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="offhand"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
      </div>
      <div id="legschoices">
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
      </div>

    </section>
  </section>


  <script>
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("click");
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
    });
    $('.feat-btn').click(function() {
      $('nav ul .feat-show').toggleClass("show");
      $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
    });
    $('.serv-btn').click(function() {
      $('nav ul .serv-show').toggleClass("show1");
      $('nav ul .second').toggleClass("rotate");
    });
    $('nav ul li').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
  </script>

  <script src="application.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**html code**

```
<section class="echoices">
      <div class="colourbar">
        <h1>COLOUR BAR GOES HERE</h1>
      </div>
        <div id="headchoices">
          <button type="button" name="head1"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
          <button type="button" name="head2"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
          <button type="button" name="head3"><img src="equipment-icons\Head.png" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div id="torsochoices">
          <button type="button" name="head"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
          <button type="button" name="torso"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
          <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Torso.png" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div id="legschoices">
          <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
          <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
          <button type="button" name="legs"><img src="equipment-icons\Legs.png" alt=""></button>
        </div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.echoices {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background: #a65c41;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.echoices button {
    display: relative;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    background: #a76e59;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.echoices button img {
    display: relative;
    margin:auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
}


#headchoices {
position: absolute;
justify-content: center;
max-height:70%;
max-width: 100%;
margin-left: 45px;
margin-right: 10px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#torsochoices, #legschoices, {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    max-height:70%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Original Javascript Code**

```
function getHead() {
    let toggleHead = document.getElementById("headchoices");
      if (toggleHead.style.display === "none") {
        toggleHead.style.display = "block";
      }

  var x = document.getElementById("torsochoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("legschoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("backchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("handchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("waistchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("feetchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("mainhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("offhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
}

function getTorso() {
  let toggleTorso = document.getElementById("torsochoices");
   if (toggleTorso.style.display === "none") {
    toggleTorso.style.display = "block";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("headchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("legschoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("backchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("handchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("waistchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("feetchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("mainhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("offhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
}

function getLegs() {
  let toggleLegs = document.getElementById("legschoices");
    if (toggleLegs.style.display === "none") {
      toggleLegs.style.display = "block";
 }
  var x = document.getElementById("headchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("torsochoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("backchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("handchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("waistchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("feetchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("mainhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
  var x = document.getElementById("offhandchoices");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

**Attempt At Changing Javascript**

```
const toggleChoices = document.querySelectorAll("#headchoices, #torsochoices, #legschoices);

function getHead() {
let arraylength = toggleChoices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
    if toggleChoices[i].style.display === "block" {
      toggleChoices[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  let toggleHead = document.getElementById("headchoices");
    if (toggleHead.style.display === "none") {
      toggleHead.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Comment: for a moment, I though the code was too long...

Comment: `.style` doesn't get styles that are inherited from CSS, it only gets inline styles. If you want the inherited style, use `getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.